# Exporting Excel tables to PNG images - how do I increase resolution?

Tags: microsoft-excel, adobe-photoshop

We are making sizecharts in Excel then copy them to photoshop. The problem is that the pictures have a low resolution 1072px wide. And as a result the sizecharts become very pixelated in PNG and making a SVG is totally out of the question.

**Question**: how can we increase the number of pixels that this image is copied and pasted to say 10.000 pixels? (for a good PNG) And maybe even create an SVG?

Process

- create table in excel
- select area and copy
- paste in photoshop
- save as PNG

Comment: Why do you need to do it in photoshop, snipping tool can do exactly the same. Why do you need it high resolution? Printing? Presentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting problem, which I've wondered about myself in the past.

I found a fairly simple workaround to achieve higher resolution PNG chart export from Excel at http://sciencestuff.xperiment.mobi/2012/12/31/saving-excel-charts-as-high-res-images-for-use-in-manuscripts-the-curse-of-pasting-into-word/, which I tested using Win7/Office 2013 before posting here:

1. In Excel, copy the chart into the clipboard
2. Paste into PowerPoint as a picture
3. From PowerPoint, right click the picture and do `Save as Picture`
4. Save as type `Enhanced Windows Metafile`
5. Open the resulting `.emf` file in Windows Paint or another bitmap editor of your choice
6. Save as PNG

When I tested this just now, the results were good: 5701x4151px, instead of 1427x1037px when the same chart was directly saved using `Save as Picture` from Excel and choosing PNG.

When following the steps above, I used MS Paint, and I had to drag the `.emf` file into Paint or use the `All files` filetype filter, since none of the other file type filters included EMF.

Answer (score 1):

I try this: Select the table and select Print. In Print Details, select 'Scale to fit'. Then save the file as PDF.
You can then open this file in Inkscape or Illustrator, and export high resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can mark the cells and then print them to a PDF from Excel. I tested this using the Microsoft Print to PDF-Printer which is included in Windows 10, didn't test other solutions. That way you can adjust the size by changing paper size/using the zoom features and open the file in photoshop afterwards. White background will be transparent in that case and you might have to add a white layer under it in photoshop before exporting to png.